# Parsing JSON returns null and question marks

Tags: python, json

I was trying to parse this JSON file to my Python code from this URL: https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=293667885&shop_id=24413460
that i took from this page https***shopee.co.id/PHILIPS-RICE-COOKER-2L-HD3128-33_sby-Area-Surabaya-i.24413460.293667885 (sorry i cannot post more than two links yet)

When I use Developer Tools to analyze the data, it was showing the attributes of the JSON file with normal-readable-strings, but when I opened the file by double-clicking it some contents appear to be hidden?

This is my code to parse that JSON file:

```
for x in range (0, 6):
with opener.open('https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/search_items/?by=sales&order=desc&newest='+ str(x*30) +'&limit=30&skip_price_adjust=false&page_type=shop&match_id=24413460') as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    for produk in data['items']:
        pid = produk["itemid"]
        new_url = opener.open('https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id='+ str(pid) +'&shop_id=24413460')
        new_data = json.loads(new_url.read().decode())
        print(new_data['name'])
```

And the result is something like this:

```
MIYAKO COUNTERTOP ????????????????????????????????????
```

I'm still new at json so I don't know what to do, any help will be appreciated.

[Screenshot of what appears in my developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFpdZ.png)

Comment: I haven't seen an API response like that. It looks like `"?"` is part of the string response. It doesn't look like an issue with how you're parsing it

Comment: Python2? Either it's a character encoding issue or the data is corrupt/supposed to be like that. Also the URL's in the code doesn't work. I'm getting 404.

Comment: Can you modify this to be self-contained (as by editing data that reproduces the issue into your code as a string, for example)? Right now others can't reproduce the behavior, and so also can't test their proposed solutions.

Comment: (that said, if the issue is just that there's content in the string that has characters not found in your current font, well, there's not much we'll be able to do about that)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It will show you the given json if you load "https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=293667885&shop_id=24413460 in browser. `requests.get(the_url)` gives 404. The "?" don't appear to be in any fields that might be sensitive. Interesting API...

Comment: so, the `?`s are there in the original JSON, so... yeah, that's on the remote system, not something caused by your Python code.

Comment: Can you support the claim that there are NUL characters in the output? I don't see anything in the code or the text of the question backing that up.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think OP might be referring to something like `"price": null` which is in the response. For my own curiosity, do you know why I can view a raw json response in browser but can't GET request it through `requests`? Can you point me in any direction on why that's different?

Comment: Ahh, so a JSON `null` / Python `None`. I was reading that as an ASCII NULL (`\u0000` in the JSON encodings that support it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it loads in the browser but not with a plain `curl` request to that URL, something about the request is triggering a different response from the server.

Chrome can give a `curl` command line for any resource loaded on the page:

[image: Devtools > Network > Copy > Copy as cURL]

This copies a request that includes all the HTTP headers:

`curl 'https://shopee.co.id/api/v1/item_detail/?item_id=293667885&shop_id=24413460' -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.3.2146560403.1506630766; _gid=GA1.3.1501700749.1506630766; _gat=1; csrftoken=yGTme9JnjopdDWv5axfOSoheC4opBno4' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3226.0 Safari/537.36' -H 'x-api-source: pc' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://shopee.co.id/PHILIPS-RICE-COOKER-2L-HD3128-33_sby-Area-Surabaya-i.24413460.293667885' -H 'authority: shopee.co.id' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'if-none-match-: 55b03-89dcbb5568d6e9410be036d2f935045d' --compressed`

Run this without changing anything to verify that it still produces the same response from the server. It does.

Remove the extra headers one by one to see if the response changes.

Be careful with `-H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` and `--compressed` since they work together, you don't want to look at raw `gzip` bytes in your terminal.

Eventually discover that `if-none-match-: 55b03-89dcbb5568d6e9410be036d2f935045d` is the header that triggers the different response from the server. Conclude that it might be some sort of caching bug in the API server.

Comment: or protection algorithm?

Comment: But does this explain the `"???"`? They don't look like they obfuscate anything important.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand how to write this in python...do I copy the curl link and paste it in my code?